# video play promise lag the video on click of pointer

Tags: javascript, video, promise

I am creating a functionality where I have some pointers which are created in series as a circle(similar to clock) one after the other, on each pointer a video source is defined. On click of any of these pointers the video source associated to that specific pointer will load in video tag. There are two video tags with id video-even and video-odd.

For example if the clicked pointer associated video loads in video-even element then the next upcoming pointer video will get pre-loaded in video-odd element but as hidden. If the video playing in video-even element ends, then the next pointer video which was pre-loaded on video-odd element will get pro-grammatically clicked and will starts to play and get visible.The video-even element will get hidden and it will pre-load the next pointer video in its element.

Basically one video element can be seen at a time.

```
                         <div id="video-even" class="vid-even video-track">
                            <video playsinline="" muted="" id="video-container-even" preload="metadata" class="bg-video no-display"
                                src="a.mp4">

                            </video>
                        </div>
                        <div id="video-odd" class="vid-odd video-track">
                            <video playsinline="" muted="" id="video-container-odd" preload="metadata" class="bg-video no-display"
                                src="b.mp4">

                            </video>
                        </div>
```

** The problem **

For mobile devices the video will pause for the first time and user have to click manually(not pro-grammatically) on pointer to play them. Therefore I have written a promise which will pause the video on mobile for the first time. But, the videos are getting hanged because of the code which was written in catch block. Please help me to find what went wrong in this code

```
    function playPromiseForMobileVideo(videoElement) {
    var playPromise = videoElement.play();
    if (playPromise !== undefined) {
        playPromise.then(
            function () {
                if (currentDevice == 'mobile' && mobileFirstTime) {
                    videoElement.pause();
                    mobileFirstTime = false;
                }
            }).catch(function(e) {
                    var index = $('#hotspot-pointer').attr('data-current-index') * 15;
                    videoElement.src = $('#dash-click-' + index).attr('data-video-src');
                    playPromiseForMobileVideo(videoElement);
            });
    }
}
```

*Catch block explanation*

As the user click on the pointer the index associated to that pointer will get store in an element with id hotspot-pointer using which we can find the element which has video url to load it in video element. The catch block is written because if some time user click too fast on random pointers one after other then the video blocks and pause and error comes from catch block.

*Note*

The pointer will pro-grammatically clicked for the first time, then the user can start with manual click but as the video ends pro-grammatical click will happen to play next video.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I see here some kind of an indefinitely recursion in your catch block. As it might fail always for mobile devices. Did you print/know the error message in your catch block?

Comment: promise is undefined